# Sending email with Servlet on GAE

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

Am writing the code as follow in my application

```
 public void send_email(String email)
 {
     Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.sendgrid.net");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication("my_username","my_password");
                    }
                });

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));

            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("ramesh@abc.com"));

            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");

            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                    "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);                


            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (AddressException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


 }
```

This is method is called in my servlet class.
After that it executed well and give a message as "`Done`" on console , but i didnt receive any email in Email-inbox.

If i run this same code as java application it works fine and received an email.

But when i  run it on Google web server its not working..
And one thing, here i removed both javaee.jar file and mail.jar files from lib, but still it didn't give any error..

Give me any suggestions guys....

Answer (score 1):

> But when i run it on Google web server its not working..

"Google web server" in your case means Google AppEngine? If so then you cannot use the full JavaMail API but must [use Google's infrastructure](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail).

> An app cannot use the JavaMail interface to connect to other mail
>   services for sending or receiving email messages. SMTP configuration
>   added to the Transport or Session is ignored.

Comment: ohh Thanks for giving replay dude..

but still i didnt get any message in my inbox ....Marcel

Answer (score 0):

Be aware you cannot send an email from just any email address.  You need to use one that is authorized in your app's domain.

> The email address of the sender, the From address. The sender address must be one of the following types:
>
> - The address of a registered administrator for the application. You can
>   add administrators to an application using the Administration Console.
> - The address of the user for the current request signed in with a
>   Google Account. You can determine the current user's email address
>   with the Users API. The user's account must be a Gmail account, or be
>   on a domain managed by Google Apps.
> - Any valid email receiving address
>   for the app (such as xxx@APP-ID.appspotmail.com).
> - Any valid email
>   receiving address of a domain account, such as support@example.com.
>   Domain accounts are accounts outside of the Google domain with email
>   addresses that do not end in @gmail.com or @APP-ID.appspotmail.com.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/sendingmail